# Best Practice of Single authentication & authorization system to use in multiple systems

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm developing a system using Yii framework and mysql
and after finishing it i'm going to develop another one.

Those two systems should be shared with the same authentication module.
And maybe there are more systems coming up.

But I don't want to have two separate module for each project doing the authentication and authorization and I don't want to assign each user two passwords.

I'm searching for a mechanism to make the A&A process done with one external and shared system and let those two systems communicate with this system to get the rights for the current logged in user.

Comment: Different DBs ? Separate hosting/domain ? Use cookie ?

Comment: Yeah different DB, different hosting/domain

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583460/how-to-implement-secure-single-sign-on-across-various-web-apps

Comment: But what about authorization?

Comment: I'm thinking of having an extra system doing the AA operations throw Rest api, but i don't have a clear idea how to make the authorization throw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement [SSO (Single Sign On)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) or to use some other method to overcome this.

Check here for a simple guide on how to implement SSO: http://merbist.com/2012/04/04/building-and-implementing-a-single-sign-on-solution/

Also check some enterprise implementations like http://www.onelogin.com/

Finally some open source implementations will probably help you like https://github.com/jasny/sso